# Нет правила для сборки цели «all»

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, redis, makefile

Переустановил систему, пытаюсь поставить RedisJSON по инструкции. **To build the module, run make in the project's directory.** Пишу `cd home/artyom/RedisJSON`, после чего пытаюсь запустить из этой директории make, но получаю

```
make -C ./src all
make[1]: вход в каталог «/home/artyom/RedisJSON/src»
make[1]: *** Нет правила для сборки цели «all».  Останов.
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/artyom/RedisJSON/src»
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Ошибка 2
```

Как пофиксить? Делал все по инструкции из https://oss.redislabs.com/redisjson/#building-and-loading-the-module. Под project's directory вообще имеется в виду то, откуда я запустил (директория клонированного проекта с гита), или надо было запускать из другого места?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, это ещё один проект, который поддался мании переписывания всего
и вся на *Rust*.  Документация, судя по всему, относится к версии
1.0, в которой проект ещё был написан на *C*.  Вот как получить
и сборать проект нужной версии:

```sh
$ git clone -b '1.0' 'https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON.git'
$ cd RedisJSON
$ make
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало! А как на будущее узнать правильный способ сборки?Вообще странная штука, неделю назад как-то ставил по этой инструкции вроде.

Comment: Ну, обычно документация не врёт.  В данном случае вам просто не повезло.  В таком случае — идти и смотреть историю проекта в репозитории.